# How to use SQL COUNT function in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, aggregate-functions

OBJECTIVE:

I am trying to get all the values in the column "test_results" from the table "test" where the studentID is the equal to some variable. I am trying to use the COUNT function in SQL to do this query however I keep getting an eror:

C# CODE:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(test_results) FROM test WHERE test.StudentID ='" + student + "';");
```

ERROR:

> "cannot find specificed column in results: test_results"

Which is weird because I have no table named "results". Where did I make an error?

Thank You

EDIT:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(test_results) AS test WHERE studentID = '" + student + "';");
```

Gets rid of the previous error however I have another error which says:

> you have an error in your SQL syntax near 'WHERE studentID = '6" at line 1

Comment: COUNT need an existing column name or just an *. Do you have a column in the table _test_ named _test_results_ ?

Comment: Your edited version has lost the `from` clause.

Comment: Yh that was eror. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
"SELECT COUNT(test_results) FROM test WHERE test.StudentID ='" + student + "';"
```

Do aliasing of the column:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as test_results FROM test WHERE test.StudentID ='" + student + "';"
```

Also, **always** use **parameterized** statement. See this post to know more:

- [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: @CsharpStudent - So you don't have a test_results column in your test table.Use `count(*)` then.

Comment: Please make a query, run it on the database directly to make sure it's working correctly and then use it in your code. If you need further help, post the table schema

Comment: Also when you say use parameterised statements, is this statement not parameterised? and if not, do you know any useful resources where I can find more information on parameterised SQL? Thank you

Comment: @CsharpStudent - Added a link in the answer for you